# How to make file from dependency JAR accessible during command line execution?

Tags: java, classpath

I have 2 projects:

Project A has folder/file.ext in src/main/resources. When built, it is present in a.jar.

Project B is referencing folder/file.ext somewhere in the code.

**I can not change project A or B or how they're built.**

When running project B from the command line with:

```
java -cp a.jar com.mycompany.mygroup.MainClass
```

I am getting a FileNotFoundException.

I'd like to know if there's a way to make this work, where folder/file.ext is made visible/available to the main class of project B without having to build a fat jar or anything like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another source folder in Project A, with the contents of Project B.

Not really sure why you would need two different projects, instead of adding all the code in one project with different packages/folders.